# dll reference from app.config?

Tags: c#

Actually i use references to reference two external dlls for my project.
I want to net set up the path in reference but force c# to search for dlls in my application path.

I created a folder in myapp ".netlibs" and put there my dlls and removed them from References section.

I put this in app.config:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <probing privatePath=".netlibs" />
</assemblyBinding>
```

But it's not working?

Do u know guys if i miss something?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please describe "not working". Do you get an error? If you don't reference them anymore, how do you load them? Please show us some code.

Comment: Hi Lars. I mean that it gives me error when trying to compile. The type or namespace "xxxxxx" could not be found....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assembly probing is only available at runtime. At compile time you always need a reference to the external assembly in your project.

What I can understand from your comment is that you are trying to compile your project without the reference.

EDIT after comment: Put the common references in source control, somewhere on a higher level and reference those. If you open your csproj file after you made the reference, the paths should be dynamic, for example: ../../References/MyReference.dll. Every developer should do a get latest of the assemblies.

Another option is to put them in the GAC on every developer machine.

Comment: Hi Gerrie.You are correct about my compiling. If i put a reference like: c:\developing\myapp\.netlibs\CSzip.dll the compiling and running it's ok. But if my colleague takes my project and put it in: c\dev\myapp the reference will not be the same anymore :| So how will he compile and run the project?

Comment: Thanks. Very good idea to put the dlls' folder in the application root and add reference to it.